# Does "Change..." option in "Something Else" during installation erase the partition contents?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I had been using dual boot with Windows 10 in an SSD and Ubuntu 18.04 in a HDD. Due to some issue with the SSD, I removed it and tried working only with the HDD with Ubuntu installed. But the system did not detect the GRUB bootloader. So I manually erased the `/boot` partition using GPARTED in a Live CD. Then went on to perform an installation where I set the freed up memory as `/boot`. After I pressed `Install Now`, It was then shown that I also need to set the `/` partition. Now, I am unsure if selecting the root partition with all of my data and changing it to `/` mount point would delete or keep all of the data. How should I proceed further?

Answer (score 2):

> Now, I am unsure if selecting the root partition with all of my data and changing it to / mount point would delete or keep all of the data. How should I proceed further?

The `/` mount point is formatted if...

- the filesystem is not POSIX compliant (`ext4`)
- you did anything with the boundaries of the partition
- you click the "format" option.

To proceed: mark the system partition as `/`, don't pick format.

**And of course before you proceed with the above you have made sure to have a backup of your personal files so if anything goes wrong you can still restore your files from that backup.**

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven't made a backup of the root directory yet as I was feeling extremely lazy, but think I will now.